# How to batch add header/footer to pdf files in Ubuntu?

Tags: pdf, batch

Is there a command or script that would help me ease the process of adding page numbers to a PDF with hundreds of pages? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## Using LaTeX!

0) Install LaTeX if necessary

1) In the following latex document replace `x.pdf` by your `file.pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,top=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\fancyfoot[RO]{Braga}
\fancyfoot[LO]{2015}
\fancyfoot[CO]{===}

\fancyhead[LO]{Lecture notes of askubuntu}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}

  \includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}},pages=1 ]{x.pdf}
  \includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},pages=2-]{x.pdf}

\end{document}
```

3) run `pdflatex addfooter.tex` and a `addfooter.pdf` will be created.

4) adapt the headers, footer (left,center, right), tune margin's sizes, etc.

Update:

Although LaTeX version give us more control over the details,
as @steeldriver, pointed out,
in some situations a `pdfjam` command line is the best choice. Typical use:

```
pdfjam --outfile newfile.pdf --pagecommand '{}' oldfile.pdf
```

Comment: The `pdfjam` package provides a possibly more convenient interface to Latex's `pdfpages` functionality e.g. `pdfjam --outfile newfile.pdf --pagecommand '{}' oldfile.pdf`

Comment: @steeldriver, thank you! `pdfjam` is always a good idea, but in this case I believe we will need to tune several details, (define margins, page size, header and footer details, and probably some unnumbered pages, etc)

Comment: thx, that helped me. can someone maybe give a hint on how to move the output of ```--pagecommand``` to the top, or more in general where can i find documentation about what is possible with ```--pagecommand```? maybe bold text or colors are interesting too. thx in advance!

Comment: @divramod here is the [pdfpages manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a much better solution myself. Rather than doing it manually as suggested above, and wasting time on figuring it out, the easiest way is to simply install [jpdftweak](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2043456/review-open-source-freebie-jpdf-tweak-gives-you-power-over-your-pdfs.html) package. It does this and more with a couple of mouse clicks. Enjoy!